# Ionic 2 Navigation and Redux

Tags: angular, ionic2, redux

My goal is to build an Ionic 2 app, with the entire application state based on Redux. So far it's working fine for stuff like "items in the menu", "login status", but i'm confused regarding Navigation.

Is it actually a good idea to handle the navigation via Redux? That would include opening and closing SideMenus.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: This may just be an opinion because I've only started with Redux and Ionic 2 though I am quite familiar with Angular 2.

I think you should manage navigation via Redux.

Since Redux is a single store for the application, and pages in Ionic 2 are simply pushed and popped off an array, I would managing that logic in Redux is really the way to go.

Similar to Redux with the react-redux-router package, you might set up a "routing:" key in your store and push pop the pages there.

I'm actually starting my first ionic 2 project for a client here soon so my expertise in that arena is limited.